# Git push multiple branches to corresponding upstream?

Tags: git

I know that setting `push.default` to `upstream` makes `git push` push the current HEAD branch to its corresponding branch in its upstream remote repo if the HEAD branch's upstream is set.

However it'd be better not having to checkout each branch for pushing. Is it possible to push each branch in the repo to its corresponding upstream at once?

Answer (score 1):

This could solve your problem

```
git config --global push.default matching
```

Comment: Not exactly, as it would push to the remote with the same name, which may be different from the upstream branch. But in most cases, it does work, yes.

Answer (score 1):

`git push --all` should be what you're looking for.

IMO, it's better than changing `push.default`'s value, as you can choose whether you want to push all the branches or not every time you push.

Also, avoid using *matching* for `push.default` because of [this](http://www.dinduks.com/git-more-control-over-git-push/).